# Modular arithmetic with floor function

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The following attached image is the problem I need help on. Thank you so much.

> Prove that $a\mod m=a-\left[\frac am\right]m$ where $$[x]=\max\left\{y\in \Bbb Z, y\leq x\right\}$$

Comment: You should include your attempts on the question

Comment: You say (three times!) that you **need** an answer. I say you that we have an urgent **need** of your attempts ...

Comment: Doesn't this look like a rewriting of the Euclidean division algorithm?

Comment: Here's a starting point- how do you define $a=b \mod m$? In number theory, we say $a\equiv b(\mod m)$ if $m$ divides $a-b$, so what you have written would be easy to show. How is it defined in your class?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would prove it with words and a minimal amount of algebra: We know that $a \ mod \ m$ gives the remainder of $\frac{a}{m}$. If we look at the decimals of $\frac{a}{m}$, it's how many times $m$ can't fit inside of $a$. E.g. we have $a = 16, m = 5$, then $\frac{16}{5} = 3.2$. here we can see that the decimal part of $3.2$, i.e. $0.2$, is how many times the $5$ can't fit inside of $16$ after the division (or in other words the remainder).

Because these two are equal we can say that $$a \ mod \ m = \Big\{\frac{a}{m}\Big\}m \tag{1}$$ Here $\{\frac{a}{m}\}$ is the decimal part of $\frac{a}{m}$.

It's quite easy to see that $$\{\frac{a}{m}\} = \frac{a}{m} - \left \lfloor \frac{a}{m} \right \rfloor \tag{2}$$

I.e. the decimal part of a fraction, is the same as the entire fraction, after you've removed the integer part of the fraction. E.g. $\{\frac{16}{5}\} = 0.2 = \frac{16}{5} - \left \lfloor \frac{16}{5} \right \rfloor = 3.2 - 3$.

Substitute these simple observations into each other, i.e. $(2)$ into $(1)$ to get: $$a \ mod \ m = \Big(\frac{a}{m} - \left \lfloor \frac{a}{m} \right \rfloor\Big)m$$

$$a \ mod \ m = a - \left \lfloor \frac{a}{m} \right \rfloor m$$

And we're done.

*Note: the floor function is the same as the max function that you defined.*